# get key value from a dictionary django/python

Tags: python, django, django-templates

How to print the value of a key from the key itself

```
dict={}
dict.update({'aa':1})
dict.update({'ab':1})
dict.update({'ac':1})
return render_to_response(t.html,  context_instance=RequestContext(request, {'dict':dict}))
```

So in this case i want to print the key `alert('{{dict.aa}}');` i.e,without using any loop can we just print the key with the reference of aa in the the above example may some thing like if {{dict['aa']}}   should give the value of aa

Comment: `dict` is a bad name for a dictionary, because it clashes with a builtin function. Also, to add an element to a dictionary, just use `d[key] = value`. Third, to retrieve a value from a dictionary, use `d[key]`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Never call a dictionary `dict`, that would overwrite the builtin `dict` type name in the current scope.

You can access keys and values in the template like so:

```
{% for item in d.items %}
    key = {{ item.0 }}
    value = {{ item.1 }}
{% endfor %}
```

or use `d.keys` if you only need the keys.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing what I think you're doing, you shouldn't be using a dictionary.  The parameters you're passing to the template are already in a dictionary.  If you're not going to loop over them you're better off putting the keys directly into the template parameters.

```
 return render_to_response(t.html,  
     context_instance=RequestContext(request, {'aa':1, 'ab': 1, 'ac':1}))
```

And now it's really easy to reference them in your template.

```
{{ aa }}
{{ ab }}
{{ ac }}
```

If you do actually need to loop over an arbitrary dictionary, then AndiDog's answer is correct.