# django template iterate ordered dict generator

Tags: python, django, generator, pycassa

I have an ordered dict generator (output from pycassa query). It has the format {'key_0': 'value_0'}

I am having trouble iterating over it.

I am trying

```
{% for k in results %}
    {{ k }}
{% end for %}
```

but I only get the key. i.e., 'key_0'

When I try `{% for k, v in results.items %}`

I get **'Content-Type' and 'text/html; charset=utf-8'** respectively

When I try `{% for k, v in results.iteritems %}`

yields no results at all

Any ideas?

Comment: Is that a tuple or a dict there?

Comment: it is a generator ordered dict...so dict

Comment: I meant in your first sentence: "It has the format ('key_0': 'value_0')".

Comment: Show how you're generating the dictionary

Comment: the answer to your question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220355/get-key-value-from-a-dictionary-django-python